# Multi-line blockquote without blank line

Tags: kramdown

This should be ridiculously easy but either I am not reading the documentation correctly or Kramdown doesn't support this. I am trying to put command-line output in a blog post, I am wanting to use a blockquote for this. However, kramdown insists on putting everything in the same blockquote on the same line.

I can put a space between each line of the blockquote but that isn't a true represenation of the output. How do I create a blockquote but each line actually be on a separate line without spaces in between each line. I guess I am looking more for "preformatted" output but I don't see that kramdown supports that.

Comment: Why not just use a [code block](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#code-blocks)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> kramdown insists on putting everything in the same blockquote on the same line

This isn’t kramdown, this is the normal behaviour of HTML. With the following markdown:

```markdown
> One
> Two
> Three
```

kramdown will create this HTML, with all the lines separate:

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>One
Two
Three</p>
</blockquote>
```

When you view this, the browser will collapse all runs of whitespace into a single space, so it will appear all on the same line:

> One
> Two
> Three

The simplest solution would be to use a [code block](http://kramdown.gettalong.org/syntax.html#code-blocks) rather than a block quote, either using indentation or a fenced code block like this:

```markdown
~~~
One
Two
Three
~~~
```

This will generate the HTML:

```html
<pre><code>One
Two
Three
</code></pre>
```

The default styling of the `pre` tag will result in the lines being separate:

```
One
Two
Three
```

If you really want to use a blockquote here, there are a couple of possible solutions. You could add two space at the end of each line to create a `<br>` element to force a line break:

(Here I’m using underscores to demonstrate where the spaces should go. You need to use actual spaces for this to work.)

```markdown
> One__
> Two__
> Three__
```

This will generate:

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>One<br />
Two<br />
Three</p>
</blockquote>
```

Another possible solution would be to apply an appropriate style to the blockquote. Kramdown allows adding `class` and `id` attributes, so you can be specific about which blocks get the style:

```markdown
<style>
.cmd-line > p {
  white-space: pre;
}
</style>

Hello

{: .cmd-line }
> One
> Two
> Three
```

The `white-space: pre` style will cause the line breaks in the source to appear in the rendered HTML.

Comment: Ahh, a code block is indeed what I wanted. I just indented the lines 4 spaces and it rendered as I expected. I didn't equate command-line output to code, thought I needed a blockquote but didn't (textbook XY problem...hah! http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: Accepted answer for the `white-space` solution. In my case I had to use `blockquote`s.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the [Hard line breaks](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.30/#hard-line-breaks)

> One
> Two
> Three